# How to know implement auto follow with react-virtualized

Tags: reactjs, react-virtualized

I am using the `List` and `WindowScroller` in react-virtualized to display logs. It seems that there is no good way to implement the auto-follow. It seems pretty easy to scroll to the bottom with `scrollToIndex`. But it is pretty hard to know whether we are at the bottom of the page. the `document.body.clientHeight` is much smaller than the `scrollTop` provided by `WindowScroller`. How could we implement this feature? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the prop "scrollToIndex" when his value is equal to your row count

```
  render(): React.Element<AutoSizer> {
const { data, ...otherProps } = this.props;
return (
  <AutoSizer onResize={this.onResizeHandler}>
    {({ width, height }) => (
      <List
        {...otherProps}
        deferredMeasurementCache={this.cache}
        rowHeight={this.cache.rowHeight}
        rowCount={data.length}
        forceUpdateGrid={data}
        rowRenderer={this.rowRenderer}
        scrollToIndex={data.length - 1}
        onScroll={this.onScrollHandler}
        height={height}
        width={width}
      />
    )}
  </AutoSizer>
);
```

}